# How to switch directories using C#?

Tags: c#, combobox, directory

(This is a continuation of the discussion on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517640/know-what-option-in-combobox-is-selected-in-c))
I have code that looks in a specific folder in the C: drive. It can tell what is in that folder, and gets what the user selects. But the problem is switching to a new Data folder to get the code from.

All the code necessary to run the program is kept in the Data folder, the company I am interning with wants to be able to switch Data folders so they can show their software off better, and have it geared towards whoever they are showing it to.

So basically my program needs to switch data folders so the company can show their software better.

Ill post all my code, its not much, so you guys can look at all of it.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
             string defaultPath = @"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\";


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                 dropdown();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //some sort of code to switch directory before close goes here
                MessageBox.Show("Data folder has been changed.", "Done");
                Application.Exit();
            }

            private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 string path =  comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

                 defaultPath = path;
            }

            private void buttonTest_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


            }
            public void dropdown()
            {
                string[] dispDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(defaultPath, "Data*");
                comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                comboBox1.Items.AddRange(dispDirectories);
            }

        }
     }
```

Comment: So drop down fills the comboBox1 correct.  and when the user selects an option from the comboBox, you set defaultPath to equal comboBox1.selectedItem.ToString().  So you have achieved what you wanted to do, now what?  You wish to switch the directory before closing..  but I dont' know which directory you wish to change.

Comment: The default path is C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Data.....but lets say you have a presentation for Apple, and the user selects the folder name Data.Apple. I want the program then to point to C:\Mavro\Mavbridge\Data.Apple instead of C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Data

Comment: Check out my answer below, you have accomplished this already.

Comment: @heinst, the problem is the filter you are specifying the GetDirecotries, for every path you pass to it, it looks for folder starting with Data and then any characters, for example Data.Apple, now when you set your path to Data.Apple, there it again looks for folder which should start with Data, you may pass the filter in the dropdown method on some condition

Comment: one other thing, if its going towards final grades or anything you might want to use proper variable names and control names. nothing major, they will just appreciate clean, easy code a lot more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question, about stripping the Default Path from the combobox display

```
//Where you load your directories
string[] dispDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\", "*.*");
// so here we will iterate through all the directories found and remove the default path from it.
for (int i=0;i<dispDirectories.Count();i++)
dispDirectories[i]=dispDirectories[i].Remove(0, defaultPath.Length);
```

Then where you set your path  change to this.  Because we removed the default Path we now have to add it again.

```
string path =  defaultPath+comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
defaultPath = path;
```

Comment: dispDirectories[i]=dispDirectories[i].Remove(0, defaultPath.Length);   keeps giving me an out of range warning....i put it inside the for loop

Comment: hrmmm...  you could have cut and pasted my code exactly as is.  You are not running the Dropdown() twice are you, cause I was under the understanding you were selecting one option then closing the program.  Once you change the default path once, you cannot change it again

Comment: no im not running it twice. yeah youre correct with im just running it once then closing it

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for all your help, I really cant thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT(@K'Leg Suggestion to make answer more clear): *If you want to get the subdirectories, after you make your first selection* you should call method `dropdown()` in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 string path =  comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                 defaultPath = path;
                 dropdown();
            }
```

A better would be receive default path as parameter in dropdown(), something on the following line

```
public void dropdown(string defaultPath)
            {
                string[] dispDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(defaultPath, "Data*");
                comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                comboBox1.Items.AddRange(dispDirectories);
            }
```

and then call dropdown method in comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged as:

```
dropdown(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

EDIT: (based on the comments on OP) the problem is the filter you are specifying for the GetDirecotries, for every path you pass to it, it looks for folder starting with Data and then any characters, for example Data.Apple, now when you set your path to Data.Apple, there it again looks for folder which should start with Data, you may pass the filter in the dropdown method on some condition

you may define the method dropdown as:

```
public void dropdown(string defaultPath, string filter)
        {
            string[] dispDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(defaultPath, filter);
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(dispDirectories);
        }
```

Then you can call the dropdown for the first time as :
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dropdown(@"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\","Data*");
        }
and then in the SelectedIndexChanged as:

```
dropdown(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),"*"); // * means select all
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your button1_Click method.   Change your message Box to

```
MessageBox.Show("Data folder has been changed to "+defaultPath,"Done");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //some sort of code to switch directory before close goes here
            MessageBox.Show("Data folder has been changed to "+defaultPath,"Done");
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

you will see that you have already changed the default Path